# Collecting commands at the same place in pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

how can one have multiple commands (collected together) at the same position in a pipe? i.e. what comes before in the pipe gets fed into each of those commands separately and sequentially, and their combined output gets fed into the next step of the pipe. For example, how could I make some variation of this pipe

`echo -e "1\n2\n3" | { head -1; tail -1; } | xargs echo`

print `1 3`, instead of just `1`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what comes before in the pipe gets fed into each of those commands separately and sequentially, and their combined output gets fed into the next step of the pipe

This is not possible since of the nature of a pipe. Once data is read from a pipe it gets removed from the pipe. That's why there can be only one reader.

I would copy the output of the first command into a temporary file and than feed it to both commands `head` and `tail`. If you launch `head` and `tail` in a subshell you can feed their combined output to another command:

Btw, a code block between curly brackets does not launch a subshell. You need to use parentheses. The following command seems the closest to what you want:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3" > file.tmp ; ( head -1 file.tmp ; tail -qn1 file.tmp; rm file.tmp ) | next_command
```

---

**About the special use case: Printing the first and the last line from a file**

I would use `sed` for that purpose:

```
sed -n '1p;$p'
```

This will print the first and the last line of a file. However it works only for files which contain at least two lines. If the file contains a single line it would get printed twice. You can get around this restriction using the following command:

```
sed -n 'x;s/^/1/;x;1p;${x;/11/{x;p}}'
```

The command above adds a `1` to the hold buffer on every line. At the end of the script (which could be after the first line) it checks if there are at least two `1` in the hold buffer and prints the last line if this is true.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my specific need (essentially the example given) but leaves the broader question unanswered so I'll leave the question open.

Comment: I added explanation for the broader question.

Comment: and the head_tail() function at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48777/command-to-display-first-few-and-last-few-lines-of-a-file shows how to generalise that sed to take more than one line from the start and end.

Comment: Yeah, a function can also being used. However it still requires to save content of the pipe into a temporary file (or variable).

Comment: Actually that particular function (unlike some others on that page) works fine in a pipe, with no temporary file.

Comment: Yes sure, since it does not read from a pipe. You pass a file name to function and then it executes `head` and on that `tail` file. It's pretty much the same as my example with the subshell `(head -n1 temp.file; tail -qn1 temp.file; rm temp.file)`

Comment: The problem isn't that you can't have multiple readers, but that `head` may consume more input than it needs for the output. Notice that `echo -e "1\n2\n3" | { read first; echo $first; tail -1; } | xargs echo` will work as desired.

Comment: Sure, of course I meant it is not possible to read the same data twice. When the data is read once it has gone. However, now where you are saying this, I wonder why `head` doesn't offer an option like `stop-after-reading-n-lines` ..